# How to scale a list of 2D coordinates to a desired size

Tags: graphics, geometry, coordinates, drawing

I have a list of 2D coordinates that draw a shape, e.g. `[{12, 14}, {22, 44}, {59, 33}, ...]`

I'd like to be able to take this shape, and center it in a canvas of arbitrary size (let's say 400x400) and have it take as much space as possible.

I've figured out how to normalize the list so it's in the 0-1 range, but ended up being stuck there when trying to then scale it up to the desired size.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find minimal and maximal values for X and Y coordinates `xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax`

Calculate point cloud width and height, and middle coordinates

```
cw = xmax - xmin
ch = ymax - ymin
mx = (xmax + xmin) / 2
my = (ymax + ymin) / 2
```

Now find coefficient

```
if cw * canvas.height >= ch * canvas.width
   coeff = canvas.width / cw   
else
   coeff = canvas.height / ch
```

Now get canvas center

```
centerx = canvas.width / 2 
centery = canvas.height / 2
```

and apply the next transformation to every point `(x,y)`:

```
screenx = centerx + coeff * (x - mx)
screeny = centery + coeff * (y - my)
```

Comment: Hmmm I tried and the shape seem to be the right size, but it's offset (i.e. not centered at all)... I wonder if I did something wrong.

Comment: I wrote just here without checking and might make a mistake, but don't see it. Point at point cloud center should be in the screen center (mx => centerx) - this is true. What is coordinate system of your canvas (origin, axes)? I meant that origin is in the corner, not in the canvas center.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! It was a typo on my end! (Mixed up a max and a min somewhere). I've fixed the issue and it is working as intended!